# Selecting years with both summer and winter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set that I have separated into the summer and winter season across multiple years. I had just realized that when I subset them by winter and summer, I end up with more winter seasons than summer seasons. I think the problem is that I have data that end at the start of summer or end when winter ends.

Is there anyway for me to set a parameter so that I am only selecting for years that have both summer and winter seasons in them?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(season_categ = case_when(month %in% 6:8 ~ 'summer',
                                  month %in% 1:3 ~ 'winter')) %>%
  group_by(ID, year, season_categ)

summer_list <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, year)%>% 
  filter(season_categ == "summer") %>% 
  group_split()

winter_list <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  filter(season_categ == "winter") %>% 
  group_split()
```

Comment: Just asking for clarification when month is neither in `1:3` nor `6:8`??

Comment: You have random numbers, so what we see will always be different than what you see. You can guard against that by using something like `set.seed(42)` (or some number) before you start using `runif`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(any(season_categ == "winter") & 
           any(season_categ == "summer"))
```

To test it, we can first remove the winter months from 2010 (for example) to get an imcomplete year:

```r
df1 %>% 
  filter(!(year == 2010 & season_categ == "winter")) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(any(season_categ == "winter") &
           any(season_categ == "summer"))
#> # A tibble: 635 x 7
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>    date            x       y    ID month  year season_categ
#>    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
#>  1 2011-01-01 69169. 880856.     1     1  2011 winter      
#>  2 2011-01-02 62891. 869748.     2     1  2011 winter      
#>  3 2011-01-03 64951. 851220.     3     1  2011 winter      
#>  4 2011-01-04 77424. 844041.     4     1  2011 winter      
#>  5 2011-01-05 75827. 861533.     5     1  2011 winter      
#>  6 2011-01-06 72937. 830014.     1     1  2011 winter      
#>  7 2011-01-07 60130. 830369.     2     1  2011 winter      
#>  8 2011-01-08 79719. 812852.     3     1  2011 winter      
#>  9 2011-01-09 60300. 845120.     4     1  2011 winter      
#> 10 2011-01-10 62817. 879759.     5     1  2011 winter      
#> # … with 625 more rows
```

This is the same as `df1 %>% filter(year != 2010)` (for my date) which means it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this.

- Years having both seasons, will have mean of months (if taken yearwise) greater than 3 but less than 6 (that's the way you've created that column).

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  filter(season_categ == "summer" &
         mean(month[season_categ %in% c('summer', 'winter')]) > 3 & mean(month[season_categ %in% c('summer', 'winter')]) < 6)
```

which should give you desired results.  But perhaps the problem is somewhere else like you may have different number of months e.g. 1,2, 6,7,8 which has both seasons but different number of rows in both subsets.

Answer (score 1):

Part of it depends on if you're using the meteorological seasons or astronomical seasons (https://www.almanac.com/content/first-day-seasons). Or if you want to nudge a season by days instead of months. Here's a suggestion that allows you to do that.

```r
seasons <- as.Date(paste0("2021-", c("01-01", "03-01", "06-01", "09-01", "12-01")))
seasons <- as.POSIXlt(seasons)$yday
seasons <- setNames(seasons, c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter"))
seasons
# winter spring summer   fall winter 
#      0     59    151    243    334 

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(
    yday = yday(date),
    season = names(seasons)[findInterval(yday, c(seasons, Inf))]
  ) %>%
  sample_n(10)
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#    date            x       y    ID  yday season
#    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> 
#  1 2010-02-13 79471. 862415.     4    43 winter
#  2 2010-10-23 61796. 813429.     1   295 fall  
#  3 2011-12-09 65958. 808064.     3   342 winter
#  4 2010-05-29 65872. 841309.     4   148 spring
#  5 2010-03-07 63789. 869548.     1    65 spring
#  6 2012-02-12 67605. 859081.     3    42 winter
#  7 2011-04-19 79034. 883803.     4   108 spring
#  8 2011-03-16 69658. 832297.     5    74 spring
#  9 2011-12-29 68793. 881267.     3   362 winter
# 10 2012-04-24 70784. 805323.     5   114 spring
```

From here, let's filter on years that have at least one of both seasons. Unfortunately, our data is fairly uniformly distributed,

```r
as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    yday = yday(date),
    season = names(seasons)[findInterval(yday, c(seasons, Inf))],
    ) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  count(season) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(year, names_from = season, values_from = n)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   year [3]
#    year  fall spring summer winter
#   <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1  2010    91     92     92     90
# 2  2011    91     92     92     90
# 3  2012    28     92     92     58
```

so we don't know if it's actually doing what we want. I'll artificially remove some data to test our desired logic:

```r
as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    yday = yday(date),
    season = names(seasons)[findInterval(yday, c(seasons, Inf))],
    ) %>%
  filter(year > 2010 | season %in% c("fall", "winter")) %>%  # artificial, for testing
  group_by(year) %>%
  count(season) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(year, names_from = season, values_from = n)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   year [3]
#    year  fall winter spring summer
#   <dbl> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1  2010    91     90     NA     NA
# 2  2011    91     90     92     92
# 3  2012    28     58     92     92
```

From here, we add a grouped filter:

```r
as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    yday = yday(date),
    season = names(seasons)[findInterval(yday, c(seasons, Inf))],
    ) %>%
  filter(year > 2010 | season %in% c("fall", "winter")) %>%  # artificial, for testing
  group_by(year) %>%
  filter(all(c("winter", "summer") %in% season)) %>%         # this is the new line
  sample_n(10)
# # A tibble: 20 x 7
# # Groups:   year [2]
#    date            x       y    ID  year  yday season
#    <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#  1 2011-02-13 61686. 815664.     4  2011    44 winter
#  2 2011-10-23 75448. 849477.     1  2011   296 fall  
#  3 2011-07-15 75901. 840969.     1  2011   196 summer
#  4 2011-05-29 66108. 811565.     4  2011   149 spring
#  5 2011-03-07 70298. 831304.     1  2011    66 spring
#  6 2011-09-18 73951. 875712.     1  2011   261 fall  
#  7 2011-08-04 64917. 860239.     1  2011   216 summer
#  8 2011-11-29 78909. 802692.     3  2011   333 fall  
#  9 2011-01-07 66441. 868062.     2  2011     7 winter
# 10 2011-06-16 64583. 889124.     2  2011   167 summer
# 11 2012-05-09 78725. 862934.     5  2012   130 spring
# 12 2012-08-12 67767. 871229.     5  2012   225 summer
# 13 2012-06-28 62354. 898829.     5  2012   180 summer
# 14 2012-05-26 62373. 819059.     2  2012   147 spring
# 15 2012-06-21 68019. 896370.     3  2012   173 summer
# 16 2012-01-22 61753. 872778.     2  2012    22 winter
# 17 2012-03-18 64490. 810292.     3  2012    78 spring
# 18 2012-08-15 76048. 875765.     3  2012   228 summer
# 19 2012-09-15 65386. 885431.     4  2012   259 fall  
# 20 2012-04-19 60072. 895292.     5  2012   110 spring
```

(Nothing from 2010, what we expect.)

---

### Data

I used a seed for reproducibility in the random data:

```r
set.seed(42)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

head(df)
#         date          x          y ID
# 1 2010-01-01 78296.1209 884829.322  1
# 2 2010-01-02 78741.5083 806274.633  2
# 3 2010-01-03 65722.7907 881984.509  3
# 4 2010-01-04 76608.9525 853936.029  4
# 5 2010-01-05 72834.9104 849902.010  5
# 6 2010-01-06 70381.9190 802222.732  1
```